# What to expect in terms of performance from my Spark Streaming Application in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I realize this might be a very broad question, but this is my issue: I developed a Spark Application in Java which uses an algorithm to analyse several JSON messages (1kB of size each) which are received through a socket connection, in one second intervals.
I'm only using 6 map methods, but the functions inside have several loops that can run up to 1000 times each (there are even cases where I have a loop inside a loop which leads to them being run 1000*1000 times in total).

I'm running the application in local mode, that is, with just one node (I assume) to perform the Spark tasks and jobs.

The problem here is that I am taking up to 7 minutes to process one of these messages, which is an insane amount of time, and causes great scheduling delays.

Is this normal given the complexity of my algorithm + running in local mode+ possibly some memory leakage?
If so, how can I proceed to improve the throughput?

Don't know if it helps, but here are some specifications of my computer:

Processor: Intel Core i5, 2.60GHz
RAM: 3.87GB usable memory
64 bit operating system

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'll give you a broad answer : You'll need to get rid of the loops first. That's your main bottleneck. And you'd also need to use "approximations" in order to improve performance. You might what to take a look about approximation theory.

Comment: You might want* to take a look at* approximation theory.

Comment: Without a [MCVE], there's nothing  we can do. We don't know what data you have, what the actual algorithm does or how we can optimize it.

Comment: next to the other comments, this does not seem related to Spark Streaming at all. You should extract the analysis logic and benchmark that separately.  If it takes 7 minutes ouside Spark Streaming, it will take 7 minutes + delta in Spark Streaming. SS will add a little overhead, but this is not your key concern at this moment. Try posting your algo in a separate question with relevant tags to get help on that.

Comment: @maasg , what do you by 'outside SS it takes 7 minutes, but inside it takes 7min+delta'? My understanding was that processing data in SS, or Spark in general would be much faster than outside, do to the use of parallel processing. Is that because I am running it in local mode, and thus have no multiple nodes to distribute the data to? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I fully understand that the algorithm is the thing I need to improve, and thank you for the insights, but I thought Spark was a way to 'compensate'for the algorithm complexity, making the data processing faster. I read that Spark is capable of processing 6GB of data per second with 100 nodes and 200 map functions for example. Am I mixing up concepts?

Comment: Spark (and spark streaming) let you parallelize a given process. Distribute it among cores (in a single system) or executors in a cluster. The key point is your unit of parallelism. If it takes 1 minute to process a single element (eg. a JSON object, a line of text, an image,...) , and your process is fully parallelizable, then given `n` cores, you could process `n` elements in the same minute + a small `delta`. That `delta` is process scheduling and coordination overhead. No magic here.  So focus on the algo first.  If you post the algo, ping me. I'm curious :-)

Comment: good read: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#other-considerations

Comment: It does compensate for algorithmic time complexity when the algorithm is designed to run in parallel. Nevertheless, looping isn't a parallel action to perform but in some cases if you know how to find the invariant, covariant and contra-variant, you might be able to transform your loop into a parallelized action.